# Sitecore - Get the field names of an item

Tags: types, sitecore, field

I want to get a list of the field names of an item, but can't get it to work.

This is my attempt so far:

```
if (pathItemInLanguage.Versions.GetVersions().Length == 0)
                        {
                            Item newItemLangVersion = pathItemInLanguage.Versions.AddVersion();

                            //Populate the new language version with values:
                            newItemLangVersion.Editing.BeginEdit();

                            newItemLangVersion.Fields.ReadAll();
                            foreach (Field field in newItemLangVersion.Fields)
                            {
                                string dn = "nix";
                                dn = field.DisplayName;
                                string n = "nix";
                                n = field.Name;
                                string k = "nix";
                                k = field.Key;
                                string xy = "nix";
                                xy = field.ToString();

                                if ((FieldTypeManager.GetField(Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields[field.DisplayName]) is HtmlField) ||
                                    (FieldTypeManager.GetField(Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields[field.DisplayName]) is TextField))
                                {
                                    newItemLangVersion.Fields[field.Name].Value = "new";
                                }
                            }
                            newItemLangVersion.Editing.EndEdit();
```

None of those strings I read from field give actual field names of the item. The application runs as module from within the Sitecore Desktop.

What am I missing?

Comment: did you try to add using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler()) ?

Comment: No, but passing an actual fieldname as string like newItemLangVersion.Fields["Title"].Value = "new"; works. Could security still be the issue?

Comment: Yes, can be an issue. Please check in debug mode what is your Sitecore.Context.UserName ? and check what rights you have on that item you want to edit

Comment: Just did that. The user is sitecore\admin, which was expected because the application runs as module from the Sitecore Desktop.

Comment: What are they values for `field.Name` and `field.Key`? Are they empty? Is there anything in them?

Comment: I think both are "__Boosting Rules". Whatever that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work using this:

```
if ((FieldTypeManager.GetField(field) is HtmlField) || (FieldTypeManager.GetField(field) is TextField)) {
...
}
```

Comment: and what happens with standard template fields ? are you updating them? :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you explain?

Comment: when you run  newItemLangVersion.Fields.ReadAll();

        foreach (Field field in newItemLangVersion.Fields)
        { is parsing all Sitecore fields including sitecore standard fields like "__Renderings,__Boosting Rules,etc and is updating this fields if are of type Text field or Html Field

Comment: Oh, I see. Will I get problems because this is what I actually do: newItemLangVersion.Fields[field.Name].Value = defaultLangItem.Fields[field.Name].ToString();

Answer (score 1):

I updated my answer. You need to do in next way: check if the field is a standard template field and check type of the field :

Please do it something like:

```
   if (pathItemInLanguage.Versions.GetVersions().Length == 0)
     {
        Item newItemLangVersion =  pathItemInLanguage.Versions.AddVersion();
        //Populate the new language version with values:
         //Populate the new language version with values:
        newItemLangVersion.Editing.BeginEdit();

        newItemLangVersion.Fields.ReadAll();

        foreach (Field field in newItemLangVersion.Fields)
        {
            if (!IsStandardTemplateField(field) && (field is HtmlField || field is TextField))
            newItemLangVersion.Fields[field.Name].Value = "new";
        }
        newItemLangVersion.Editing.EndEdit();
      }
```

and you have a method to check if is a template field because you don't need to modify that kind of fields

```
  public bool IsStandardTemplateField(
       Field field)
    {
        Sitecore.Data.Templates.Template template = Sitecore.Data.Managers.TemplateManager.GetTemplate(
          Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.DefaultBaseTemplate,
          field.Database);
        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsNotNull(template, "template");
        return template.ContainsField(field.ID);
    }
```

Comment: That wouldn't work for me because I have lots of different items with different fields. I need a generic way to do this.

Comment: I want to run through items, create versions for all languages under System/Languages and pupulate the textfields and HTML fields with dummy text. Item version creation for all languages already works, but I cannot get the dummy text into the items. The difficult part is that the items are based on different templates so they have different fieldtypes and fieldnames.

Comment: Gave that a try, but still no text in the new version. The Visual Studio gives a warning that the condition field is HtmlField and the other are never met. "Warning1: The given expression is never of the provided ('Sitecore.Data.Fields.HtmlField') type"